# what is the best approach to query custom customer data. MongoDB / ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I'm doing a application that customers could sent custom data and this custom data should be "queryable", I mean the customer could search for these fields.

Data sent for the user below:

```
data = {
  name: "Thiago",
  id: 2093  
  country: "Portugal",
  custom_data: {
    company: "foo",
     plan: "pro",
     department: "it",
     sessions: 203 
  }
}
```

Due to the application scheme-less requirement, we are using mongoDB to persist data.

But, I'm wondering how to query these custom data? We don't have index for these fields and there are a lot of documents ~ 1.3M.

I think that using elasticsearch we can handle this requirement, but is there a good approach without using it ? only using mongodb ?

One query example could be:

> Find all from Portugal and have more than 100 logins.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have arbitrary documents and arbitrary queries? If so, then queries are going to be SLOW every time they're performed as every document would need to be scanned. Even with everything in memory, that's not going to be fast or efficient unfortunately without an index.

Comment: @WiredPrairie right. Im using elasticsearch to index my documents. Each tenant will have your own index inside ES. I wonder if this approach is correct, what do you think ? is elasticsearch a good approach for this scenario ?

Comment: Given that you want datatypes (>100) and you can't create indexes on every combination (as there's a max of 64 indexes per collection, with a recommendation to stay under 16 regularly), I can't see a good effective/logical way to model this in MongoDB. There might be one, but it's not obvious.

Comment: @WiredPrairie yeah ! What about using ES with automatic mappings for custom fields ? This way , I think is much better than , as you mentioned, create one index/combination for all fields.

Comment: I've never worked with ES, so I can't offer any guidance there.

Comment: Thanks @WiredPrairie appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your data to be dynamically queried as an array of "typed" key-value pairs, like so:

```
 query_data: [
    { type: "company", value: "foo" },
    { type: "plan", value: "pro" },
    ... 
  ]
```

and then index on .type and .value

Given your example, this would look like this:

```
> db.xx.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515ca2bc57a0887a97cc8d14"),
    "name" : "Thiago",
    "id" : 2093,
    "country" : "Portugal",
    "custom_data" : [
        {
            "type" : "company",
            "value" : "foo"
        },
        {
            "type" : "plan",
            "value" : "pro"
        },
        {
            "type" : "department",
            "value" : "it"
        },
        {
            "type" : "sessions",
            "value" : 203
        }
    ]
}
> db.xx.ensureIndex({country:1,"custom_data.type":1,"custom_data.value":1})
> db.xx.find({country:"Portugal","custom_data.type":"sessions","custom_data.value":{$gt:100}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor country_1_custom_data.type_1_custom_data.value_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "country" : [
            [
                "Portugal",
                "Portugal"
            ]
        ],
        "custom_data.type" : [
            [
                "sessions",
                "sessions"
            ]
        ],
        "custom_data.value" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Aspire-5750:27017"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ronasta ! Really enjoy you answer. Solve my problem !